# Shopware5 auto code review - "finally" not supported

Tags: php, e-commerce, shopware

I submitted a plugin in shopware.
The shopware auto code review rejected the plugin because it contains a file that has a `finally` from a `try/catch/finally` block. 
On my view, the code is valid and should not fail.

I tested the plugin on (my local) DEV system shopware v5.3.7 and it ran as expected.

I tested the rejected file (the one with the finally) on this site https://www.piliapp.com/php-syntax-check/ and the validation from php versions >= v5.5.38 worked fine. No syntax errors.

Since the minimum requirements for shopware are php >= 5.6.4, I would not expect this auto code review to fail.

Does anyone know why this rejection might have happened? 
Also, like a magento validator (https://github.com/magento/marketplace-tools) does anyone know if there is something similar from shopware where we can just download the (php) file and run a syntax/quality check on our plugin locally before upload?
Thanks

Comment: there's no way it worked on PHP 5.3. Look https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php 5.5+

Comment: Upgrade your system to a supported version of PHP. See here https://secure.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: @delboy1978uk Thanks, but I wrote *shopware* v5.3.7 not php. 5.3 refers to shopware version, not php.

Comment: ah, apologies!!

Comment: regarding quality, `composer require --dev phpro/grumphp`, check it out here https://github.com/phpro/grumphp